# geom_density in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have created the below density plot in ggplot2 which shows a nice regional distribution, however the blue line across the bottom and a small part of the vertical on the left and the green and blue on the vertical on the right ruins the plot.

I have used geom_density to plot the below, is there a way of removing the above mentioned so only the curves are visible?

[image]

Code below:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=d$MEI)) + 
  geom_density(data=d, aes(x=d$MEI, group=d$Region, colour = Region),alpha=0.5, adjust=2) + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+
  xlab("MEI") +
  ylab("Density")+
  theme(axis.text.y      = element_text(size=14),
        axis.text.x      = element_text(size=14),
        axis.title.y     = element_text(size=14),
        axis.title.x     = element_text(size=14),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line        = element_line(colour = "black"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border     = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA)
  )
```

Many Thanks!

```
stat_density(data=d, geom = "line",aes(x=d$MEI, group=d$Region, colour = Region),adjust=2)+
```

[image]

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate, use `stat_density` combined with `geom="line"` (instead of `geom_density`)

Comment: David, this worked in that it removed the unwanted line features but the shape and size of the curves are now completely different, would you expect stat_density to return similar results?

Comment: Tty adding `position="identity"` you need to scale your curves

Comment: position="identity" worked, sorry for my ignorance but what do you mean when you mention scaling of curves? Thanks